# Powerpoint Command Line Switch \s for online presentation

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint-2016

I have a shared presentation I want to show on a screen in my office. I'm using a feature in Powerpoint that allows you to edit an online (OneDrive) presentation collaboratively, and update it on-the-run.

When the computer starts, I want it to jump to the slideshow automatically. For that I created a shortcut that runs the slideshow using the \s switch. Unfortunately I only get it to work on local files and not on the cloud.

E.G, if the link is:
`"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office16\POWERPNT.EXE" /S localfile.pptx`
It works.

But if the link is
`"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office16\POWERPNT.EXE" /S https://1drv.ms/p/s!...`
It will not work.

A solution I already tried is saving the file as a ppsx or pptx on a synced OneDrive folder. The problem is it is not updated automatically after edit. I need Powerpoint to open it as a file on cloud.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: OK, I still have a problem. Apparently this way it downloads the presentation and does not show it as a live file so no edits are auto updated and I have to re-open the presentation. Any ideas?

Comment: Oh well, I solved this too... This only works on an Office 365 subscription

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found an answer. (I don't understand the self-answer policy from the help seciton so if I violate it please remove the question.)

I have found out that there is another URL for a cloud file that starts with https://d.docs.live.net/ - You can see it when going to recent files on the Open menu. You can right click and copy that link and use it for the command line switch.

=)

Comment: Just make sure you have the right permission set when you click the share button while editing the presentation.